# export command within shell script

Tags: shell, shell-scripting

When I use export command at command prompt, it works as expected. But it does not work from shell script.

```
[root@server shantanu]# export myip=10
[root@server shantanu]# echo $myip
10
[root@server shantanu]# vi myip.sh
#!/bin/sh
export myipadd=10

[root@server shantanu]# sh -xv myip.sh
#!/bin/sh
export myipadd=10
+ export myipadd=10
+ myipadd=10

[root@server shantanu]# echo $myipadd
```

I want to make the variable available to the same script next time when it runs. In other words I am looking for some way to memorize the variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `export` command from the command line make the environment variables only take effect in the current session. Add it to your shell startup files for permanent.

For example, with bash:

```
echo "export myipadd=10" >> ~/.bash_profile (for only root)
echo "export myipadd=10" >> /etc/profile (for all users)
```

Comment: Thanks. Next time the myipadd will change to 12. How do I update profile? Or can I simply add it twice and profile will read the last entry for myipadd ? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: It did not work on my centOS box. I am getting blank line returned.

Comment: You can use `sed` to change it, for e.g: `sed -i 's/export myipadd=10/export myipadd=12/' /etc/profile`

Comment: Make it take effect with `source /etc/profile` or just logout and login back.

Comment: Or this, much cleaner to me: `echo "export myipadd=<your_ip_add>" > ~/.myipadd` and then add the line `source ~/.myipadd` to either `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`.  That way you don't need to fool with SED on your profile script (could be dangerous =).

Comment: echo "export myipadd=199" > ~/.myipadd ; source /etc/profile # this works as expected at command prompt but the same line does not work if it is part of shell script!

Comment: You must add `source ~/.myipadd` to `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to export your variable within a shell script and make it available to other scripts, you need to use the `source` command.

```
$ cat test.sh
export MY_VAR="hello"
$ source test.sh
$ echo $MY_VAR
hello
```